# Gnuplot, how to add a grid without ticks?

Tags: gnuplot

I have something like:

```
set grid xtics lt 0 lw 1 lc rgb "#a9a9a9"
set grid ytics lt 0 lw 1 lc rgb "#a9a9a9"
```

or the same without the "xtics" tag, and that works fine!
But if i add:

```
unset xtics
```

Then the grid disappears too :(

How can I only have a grid, without tics?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To hide the major ticks, you can use `set tics scale 0`:

```
set grid
set tics scale 0
plot x
```

[image]

Note, if one day you also want to use minor ticks and also hide them, you must use `set tics scale 0,0.001`.

Answer (score 11):

If you only want to make the tic labels disappear then use `set format`:

```
set format x ""
set format y ""
set grid
plot x
```

[image]

If you don't want the tics either, then as far as I know you'd need a more complicated script, possibly using iterators and arrows, for example the following (you'll have to change the limits depending on your `xrange` and `yrange` and the arrow style to your liking):

```
unset xtics
unset ytics
set for [i=-5:5:5] arrow from i,-10 to i,10 nohead
set for [j=-5:5:5] arrow from -10,j to 10,j nohead
plot x
```

[image]